# how to copy a sheet from external to current workbook and saving that sheet as a new work book

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am working on an excel automation. I have a main workbook which has two sheets i.e. dashboard and data1. I need to fetch a sheet from another workbook(whose name can be anything i.e its not fixed. consider it as filex.xls) placed in the D: drive and paste the entire sheet to the data1 sheet. I need to perform some operations on that sheet then save data1 sheet as a new workbook in C: drive with the same name as the original file followed by modified (i.e. filexmodified.xls)

Comment: Cool story. So do you have a question or something?

Comment: the question is , how to i execute this story ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was a bit cynical. Did you try anything? Do you have a piece of code? Do you have a **specific programming related question**? Or do you just hope that we will write the code for you? Because, and I'm sure you know this, StackOverflow is a programmer's help site, not a free code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

To import the data:

`Workbooks.Open PATH
Worksheets(1).UsedRange.copy data1.cells(1) 'data1 should be a Worksheet Variable
ActiveWorkbook.Close False`

For saving as new Workbook:

`ThisWorkbook.SaveAs PATH`